# All rows from LEFT and RIGHT put in a stack

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get all the rows from TABLE A altogether with the matching rows from TABLE B stacked under the same columns.

Table A :

```
    SomeCol  | Value
    1        | NULL
    1        | NULL
    2        | NULL
    2        | NULL
```

Table B :

```
SomeCol      | Value
    1        | X
    1        | Y
    2        | Z
    2        | A
```

I tried using OUTER APPLY operator, because its definition says that it takes the rows from the left table(A) altogether with the unmatching rows from the right table(B).

```
SELECT 
    A.SomeCol,
    A.Value,
    B.*
FROM
    TableA as A
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT X.SomeCol, X.Value FROM TableB AS X
    WHERE A.SomeCol = X.SomeCol
) AS B
```

I expect something like this :

```
SomeCol | Value
1       | NULL
1       | NULL
1       | X
1       | Y
2       | NULL
2       | NULL
2       | Z
2       | A
```

Short update : I forgot to mention, I am not allowed to use a UNION, as I want to return results only for existing rows in Table A.

Comment: Use `UNION` clause

Comment: There's still no adequate explanation of why UNION is not acceptable. Please expand your example to include a case where it wouldn't be suitable

Comment: The UNION is not acceptable because I don't need everytime a huge dataset between the two tables. I only need the results for existing rows in Table A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `union all` in a sub-query is perhaps easiest

```
select u.SomeCol, u.Value
from (
  select SomeCol, Value
  from A
  union all
  select SomeCol, Value
  from B
) as u
order by u.SomeCol;
```

***Edit after question updated***

There is nothing to prevent the inner query having filters:

```
select u.SomeCol, u.Value
from (
  select SomeCol, Value
  from A
  union all
  select SomeCol, Value
  from B
  where SomeCol in (select SomeCol from A)
) as u
order by u.SomeCol;
```

to only include rows from `B` that have matching rows in `A`. I would still use a `union` here so the rows from `B` remain separate rows in the output of the query.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I can't use a UNION in this query, as I don't want everytime to get a lot of results.

Comment: @BogdanCioată `union` is still the right answer, even if the rows from one table need to be filtered by the other table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   Create Table TableA
(
SomeCol int, Value Varchar(5)
)

Create Table TableB
(
SomeCol int, Value Varchar(5)
)

Insert into TableA (SomeCol, Value) Values     
    (1, NULL),
    (1, NULL),
    (2, NULL),
    (2, NULL)

Insert into TableB (SomeCol, Value) Values     
    (1, 'X'),
    (1, 'Y'),
    (2, 'Z'),
    (2, 'A')

    SELECT SomeCol, Value FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT SomeCol, Value FROM(
SELECT 
    B.SomeCol, B.Value
FROM
    TableA as A
INNER JOIN TableB AS B
    ON A.SomeCol = B.SomeCol
)a
```

The output is as shown below

```
SomeCol Value
-------------
1       NULL
1       NULL
2       NULL
2       NULL
1       X
1       Y
2       A
2       Z
```

You can find the live demo [**here**](https://rextester.com/IFEW44264).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the request correctly, you want to retunrn all the rows from TableA and only the matching rows from TableB, but not in the same tuple/row (based on what you expect).

This means that a full join will not work. I think you should you a union all like this:

```
-- all rows from TableA
 SELECT 
    A.SomeCol,
    A.Value,
FROM TableA

UNION ALL 
-- mathing rows in TableB
 SELECT 
    A.SomeCol,
    A.Value,
FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableB.SomeCol = TableA.SomeCol
```